# Javascript Gravity Effect

Tags: javascript, effects, gravity

I'm making a new website and now I'm creating the animations but I have a problem. For a logo I want to use a hanging wood sign (like this [one](http://previews.123rf.com/images/ninell/ninell1106/ninell110600049/9737232-wooden-sign-hanging-on-the-chains-isolated-on-a-white-background-Stock-Photo.jpg)). I want to make it shaking because of the wind. I think I need to use a gravity engine. I've made [the parts](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2Mzrj9C8xAeGRwbl9xX0NZbjQ/view) of it but don't know how to connect and make them shaking. The chains should look something like [this](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/box2d/chain). The user won't be able to interact with it. When the page is load the effect will start - the sign will be pulled from a high, then it will continue more weak shaking. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you show what you have done so far.

Comment: @Damon [the parts](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2Mzrj9C8xAeGRwbl9xX0NZbjQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is not trivial to accomplish, and I can tell you now that you aren't going to get a good answer if you aren't more specific - try parameterizing the problem a bit better (edit your question, don't post it as a comment). Do you want some kind of "wind effect" to rattle the sign or just have that happen once when the page loads? Does it move left to right or drop down? Do you want the user to be able to interact with it? Have you tried anything (code wise)? Do you have a visual example (gif or video) you can go off of?